# Multiple criteria find min and max date values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, criteria, min

I browsed for hours so far and couldn't find a solution for this problem. Would appreciate help here. I am newbie.

I am trying to find max and min dates using excel 2016 without microsoft 365 subscription so I don't have MINIFS function I would like use any functions which are available in excel 2016.

```
Build Country type year Date
A NA Build 2020 7/8/2020
B NA Build 2020 3/23/2020
A NA Build 2021 3/23/2020
B NA Build 2021 11/16/2020
A NA Build 2020 8/28/2020
B EU Build 2020 1/13/2020
A EU Build 2020 11/20/2020
B EU New 2020 7/17/2020
A NA Build 2020 3/28/2020
A NA Build 2020
A EU New 2020 3/16/2020
B NA New 2021 11/4/2020
A NA New 2021 5/4/2020
B NA New 2021 9/28/2020


Max Date Min Date
A NA Build 2020 8/28/2020 3/28/2020
```

For min Date I would like to ignore blanks.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option without array entered formulas.

For Max:

```
=AGGREGATE(14,6,(A19=$A$2:$A$15)*(B19=$B$2:$B$15)*(C19=$C$2:$C$15)*(D19=$D$2:$D$15)*E2:E15,1)
```

For Min:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,(1/(--(ISNUMBER($E$2:$E$15))*(A19=$A$2:$A$15)*(B19=$B$2:$B$15)*(C19=$C$2:$C$15)*(D19=$D$2:$D$15)))*$E$2:$E$15,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Have not seen this method before! Def the way to go assuming actual data set is probably much larger

Answer (score 1):

These are both array formulas that must be confirmed with  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  +  <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>  +  <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

---

**Max:** `=MAX(IF((A2:A15=A20)*(B2:B15=B20)*(C2:C15=C20)*(D2:D15=D20),E2:E15))`
**Min:** `=SMALL(IF((A2:A15=A20)*(B2:B15=B20)*(C2:C15=C20)*(D2:D15=D20),E2:E15),2)`

---

[image]

*Screen shot for cell references*